# Wondering why scipy.spatial.distance.sqeuclidean is twice slower than numpy.sum((y1-y2)**2)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.spatial import distance

y1=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
y2=np.array([0. , 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0.7, 0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ])

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    distance.sqeuclidean(y1,y2)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

---15.212640523910522 seconds---

```
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    np.sum((y1-y2)**2)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

---8.381187438964844--- seconds

I supposed that the Scipy is kind of optimized so it should be faster.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: scipy uses numpy under the hood, so it just can't beat plain numpy (assuming good numpy coding). If you check the code for `sqeuclidean`, you'll see it adds a bunch checks + extra options, which comes at a typically marginal cost, but if this cost hurts you and you don't care about the extra scipy offers, then don't use it...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more comprehensive comparison (credit to @Divakar's `benchit` package):

```
def m1(y1,y2):
  return distance.sqeuclidean(y1,y2)

def m2(y1,y2):
  return np.sum((y1-y2)**2)

in_ = {n:[np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n)] for n in [10,100,1000,10000,20000]}
```

[image]

scipy gets more efficient for larger arrays. For smaller arrays, the overhead of calling the function most likely outweighs its benefit. According to [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L617-L668), scipy calculates `np.dot(y1-y2,y1-y2)`.

And if you want an even faster solution, use `np.dot` directly without the overhead of extra lines and function calling:

```
def m3(y1,y2):
  y_d = y1-y2
  return np.dot(y_d,y_d)
```

[image]