# Get the distance to each nearest element in a 1D/2D without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working in python using numpy (could be a pandas series too) and am trying to make the following calculation:

Lets say I have an array corresponding to points on the x axis:

```
2, 9, 5, 6, 55, 8
```

For each element in this array I would like to get the distance to the closest element so the output would look like the following:

```
3, 1, 1, 1, 46, 1
```

I am trying to find a solution that can scale to 2D (distance to nearest XY point) and ideally would avoid a for loop. Is that possible?

Comment: @jsotola That is not true. In fact looping with numpy is slow and a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a theme with O(N^2) solutions here. For 1D, it's quite simple to get O(N log N):

```
x = np.array([2, 9, 5, 6, 55, 8])
i = np.argsort(x)
dist = np.diff(x[i])
min_dist = np.r_[dist[0], np.minimum(dist[1:], dist[:-1]), dist[-1]])
min_dist = min_dist[np.argsort(i)]
```

This clearly won't scale well to multiple dimensions, so use [`scipy.special.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) instead. Assuming your data is N-dimensional and has shape `(M, N)`, you can do

```
k = KDTree(data)
dist = k.query(data, k=2)[0][:, -1]
```

Scipy has a Cython implementation of `KDTree`, [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). Sklearn has a [`sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) with a similar interface as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1**

You can use broadcasting in order to get matrix of distances:

```
>>> data = np.array([2,9,5,6,55,8])
>>> dst_matrix = data - data[:, None]
>>> dst_matrix
array([[  0,   7,   3,   4,  53,   6],
       [ -7,   0,  -4,  -3,  46,  -1],
       [ -3,   4,   0,   1,  50,   3],
       [ -4,   3,  -1,   0,  49,   2],
       [-53, -46, -50, -49,   0, -47],
       [ -6,   1,  -3,  -2,  47,   0]])
```

Then we can eliminate diagonal as proposed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736258/deleting-diagonal-elements-of-a-numpy-array):

```
dst_matrix = dst_matrix[~np.eye(dst_matrix.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(dst_matrix.shape[0],-1)
>>> dst_matrix
array([[  7,   3,   4,  53,   6],
       [ -7,  -4,  -3,  46,  -1],
       [ -3,   4,   1,  50,   3],
       [ -4,   3,  -1,  49,   2],
       [-53, -46, -50, -49, -47],
       [ -6,   1,  -3,  -2,  47]])
```

Finally, mininum items can be found:

```
>>> np.min(np.abs(dst_matrix), axis=1)
array([ 3,  1,  1,  1, 46,  1])
```

**Approach 2**
If you're looking for time and memory efficient solution, the best option is `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`s which packs points (of any dimension) into specific data structure that is optimized for querying closest points. It can also be extended to 2D or 3D.

```
import scipy.spatial
data = np.array([2,9,5,6,55,8])

ckdtree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(data[:,None])
distances, idx = ckdtree.query(data[:,None], k=2) 
output = distances[:,1] #distances to not coincident points
```

For each point querying first two closest points is required here because first of them is expected to be coincident. This is the only solution I found between all the proposed answers that doesn't take ages (the average performance is 4secs for 1M points). **Warning:** you need to filter duplicated points before applying this method.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of achieving it. Some readable and generalizable ways are:

**Approach 1**:

```
dist = np.abs(a[:,None]-a)
np.min(dist, where=~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool), initial=dist.max(), axis=1)
#[ 3  1  1  1 46  1]
```

**Approach 2**:

```
dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a,a))
np.min(dist, where=~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool), initial=dist.max(), axis=1)
```

**For a 2-D case approach 1** (assumes Euclidean distance. Any other is also possible):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dist = cdist(a,a)
np.min(dist, where=~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool), initial=dist.max(), axis=1)
```

**For a 2-D case approach 2** with numpy only:

```
dist=np.sqrt(((a[:,None]-a)**2).sum(-1))
np.min(dist, where=~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool), initial=dist.max(), axis=1)
```

You can achieve a [faster distance calculation by using `np.dot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63594244/4975981).

Comment: This will fail if the array has repeated values, as their distance will be zero, which is filtered out of the `min` calculation. Try: `np.min(dist, where=np.eye(len(a))==0, initial=dist.max(), axis=0)`

Comment: This is O(n^2).

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point. I will add a nlog(n) solution too.

Comment: I just posted one

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeap exactly had that in mind. Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some list comprehension on a pandas series:

```
s = pd.Series([2,9,5,6,55,8])
s.apply(lambda x: min([abs(x - s[y]) for y in s.index if s[y] != x]))
Out[1]: 
0     3
1     1
2     1
3     1
4    46
5     1
```

Then you can just add `.to_list()` or `.to_numpy()` to the end to get rid of the series index:

```
s.apply(lambda x: min([abs(x - s[y]) for y in s.index if s[y] != x])).to_numpy()

array([ 3,  1,  1,  1, 46,  1], dtype=int64)
```