# Calculate distances among a set of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, euclidean-distance

Is there a more efficient way to calculate the Euclidean distance among a given set of points?

This is the code I use:

```
def all_distances(position):
    distances = np.zeros((N_circles, N_circles))
    for i in range(N_circles):
        for j in range(i, N_circles):
            distances[i][j]=calculate_distance(position[i], position[j])
    return distances

def calculate_distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2+(p1[1]-p2[1])**2)
```

`position` is an array containing the coordinates of `N_circles` points.

Comment: your code is efficient and easily readable. It is good

Comment: If your code works but you want to improve it, [codereview.se] is probably a better site. That said, it would help to know what you would consider an improvement. Better time efficiency? Less memory use? neither/both?

Comment: Thank you G. Anderson. I didn't know about the Code Review site. Anyway my goal is to have my code more time efficient, since it has to be cycled many times.

Comment: @FedericoMancini if you want improved performance over existing modules like scipy, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63594244/4975981 with performance comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and [squareform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) from scipy

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

distances = pdist(position, metric="euclidean")
distance_matrix = squareform(distances)
```

Comment: Thank you! With 1000 points and 10 cycles, my code runs in 12.82 sec vs 0.08 sec with the pdist and squareform functions. A great improvement.

Comment: I wonder if that diff comes from C code in the library versus "interpreted" python code?

Comment: Note that `squareform` is not necessary in nearly all cases. The "condensed" distance matrix commonly includes all information needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linalg` to calculate the norm. Also you can define a function that calculate a hypersphere equation that include circle

```
import numpy as np

def distance(w, x, b=0):
    w_norm = np.linalg.norm(w,2)
    return abs(np.dot(w,x) + b) / w_norm
```

Answer (score 1):

`**2` may use some "power" subroutine.  It may be faster to use a multiply.

If there is a `hypot()` in the library, use it.

You are keeping the distance from `i` to `j` (where `i <= j`).  Maybe you want to store `[j][i]` also?

Alternatively, when looking up the distance you can use `min(i,j)` to 'max(i,j)`.  (I can't tell whether this is less overhead.)

The code seems to compute `[i][i]`.  Won't that always be zero?  That is, perhaps you need `range(i+1, N_circles)`.  And you may or may not need to store `0`.

Do all the distances change every time?  If not, is there some way to recompute only the ones that changed?  (This is a sample of "out of the box" thinking.  There may be other tricks that can be used.)

Here's another...

Don't use SQRT at all.  Instead, keep the squared distances.  It is sufficient for deciding which is "closer" -- *if that is all you need it for*.  (I used this out-of-the-box trick successfully in one project.)

How many times do you look up a 'distance' before recomputing it?  If <= 'once', then don't bother pre-calculating.  Simply calculate on the fly.  (Actually the cutoff is a little more than 1.0, because of the overhead of creating and maintaining `distance[]`)